# If 2 checkboxes true then add cell value - Excel Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to add a list of prices depending on if 2 check boxes are ticked.

What I want to do is say if the paid checkbox is ticked and the just eat tickbox is ticked then add get the number in the price column and add them up together.

I've looked at the below link which has helped me add up the total of orders that are marked as not paid but I can't work out how to do the above.

[image]

[link used for help](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-excel-check-boxes-to-create-a-list-totaling-spreadsheet/)

Comment: please share with us your formulas you already have

Comment: The only formula I have been able to work for myself is from the link within the question. Thanks

Comment: So please **share your formula** (that you worked out from the link), not just the link.

Comment: I don't see why this helps but ok the formula I used was =IF(L3=TRUE,B3,"0") Then it was a matter of doing A3*L3 to give me either 22 or 0 and then add them up :)

Comment: I am trying to use the following to achieve the result but get a #VALUE! error 
=SUMPRODUCT(($O$1:$O$16=TRUE)+$A$1:$A$32)

Comment: I think I'm getting closer but this is still not working...
=SUMIF(N3:N8,"=true",((R3:R8,"=true"),A3:A32)
What am I doing wrong?